# Is it possible to make smooth page navigation transitions in Wicket?

Tags: javascript, java, css, css-transitions, wicket

I would like to make some smooth transitions between pages navigation in Wicket Java framework. Is it possible with Wicket tools, javascript and css? I cant find a way to do that.

Thanks for any answer.

Comment: Hi,
could you elaborate a little more about "smooth" transition? Do you want to use some kond of animation or you just want to use some AJAX to refresh some portions of your page?

Comment: I would like to slowly for example fade out previous page and in same time roll to it e.g. from left the new page, which link has been clicked before. I have found only the ways, how to do in e.g. vue.js, but it is whole framework for making webapps. I would like to obtain similar behaviors (very simply animation), when Wicket changes the pages. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wicket does not provide solutions for this. Most of the Wicket applications use either full page re-remder/redirect or Ajax for updating just part(s) of the page, but not the whole body.

I'd suggest you to try with CSS Keyframes. The idea is to add CSS class to the body of your pages on these two JS events: `beforeunload` and `DOMContentLoaded` (aka `domready`). When `beforeunload` is fired you need to remove `fade-in` and add `fade-out` CSS class. And do the opposite for `DOMContentLoaded`.

The CSS will look like:

```
/* make keyframes that tell the start state and the end state of our object */

 @-webkit-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
 @-moz-keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }
 @keyframes fadeIn { from { opacity:0; } to { opacity:1; } }

 .fade-in {
      opacity:0;  /* make things invisible upon start */
      -webkit-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;  /* call our keyframe named fadeIn, use animattion ease-in and repeat it only 1 time */
      -moz-animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;
      animation:fadeIn ease-in 1;

      -webkit-animation-fill-mode:forwards;  /* this makes sure that after animation is done we remain at the last keyframe value (opacity: 1)*/
      -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
      animation-fill-mode:forwards;

      -webkit-animation-duration:1s;
      -moz-animation-duration:1s;
      animation-duration:1s;
 }
```

I am not very good in CSS so better ask Google for more info.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will try that. :) So solution is work only with javascript and css, right?

Comment: Yes. Pure JS and CSS! No Wicket/Java code is needed.

Comment: Perfect, I will try. :) Thank you very much.

Comment: It is working, I didnt try fade-out yet, because I think, that wicket will change the pages instantly so the beforeunloud wouldnt work, but fade-in is working. Perfect ! :) I had to add to body style visible hidden, because Wicket flashing and then animating, but this way is working. On domContentLoaded the fade-in class is added and visible is added. :)

Comment: Fade-out is not working because pages are change instantly by wicket. Maybe some delay could be there...

Comment: I have found out, that is possible to add Thread.sleep into constructor of the pages. This sleep has same long, that fade-out animation, so now both (fade-in and fade-out) animations are working. :)

Comment: So now, your users enjoy animations but experience slower page loads :-) Life is not perfect!

Comment: :D I will focus only on fade-in animations. :) Problem is, that with this now the page somehow throws StalePageException and starts to infinite reloading again and again. I have used AjaxEventBehavior for domReady and unload events.

Comment: Ajax Event Behavior makes an Ajax call which is not needed at all. Write the needed JS yourself directly in the HTML. 'window.addEventListener'